# How to catch the task exception in java fx application?

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, executorservice

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

import javafx.concurrent.Task;


public class T {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

        Task t = new Task(){

            @Override
            protected Object call() throws Exception {
                System.out.println(1/0);
                return null;
            }

        };

        //My progresss Bar in JavaFX
        //Progressbar.progressProperty().bind(t.progressProperty());

        Future future = executorService.submit(t);

        try {
            future.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  //returns null if the task has finished correctly.

        executorService.shutdown();


}
}
```

I have a code that resembles something like this my code task has internal method call in object call that throws sql exception but i can never catch it in the Executor service also just above the submit call i have a progressbar of javafx but that also seems to get stuck like the main ui hangs when using future . without future the progress bar works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Future.get` is a blocking call. This is why the UI hangs.

Do not use the `Future` to get the result. Instead use the `Task`'s `onSucceeded` event handler. The `onFailed` event handler can be used to get the exception. Example:

```
t.setOnSucceeded(evt -> System.out.println(t.getValue()));
t.setOnFailed(evt -> {
    System.err.println("The task failed with the following exception:");
    t.getException().printStackTrace(System.err);
});
executorService.submit(t);
```

BTW: Both handlers run on the JavaFX application thread and can therefore safely be used to modify the UI to show the result/error to the user.